# Dieting and exercise

Tags: diet, health

Hi I am a girl and I weigh 61kg and I'm about 160cm and I'm just need your help to see if I'm doing anything right all wrong. So every morning I have raw egg and milk for breakfast a salad or for lunch and meat for dinner, I do about 10 min of cardio and core workouts and weights and work on my legs, I'm not sure if you know who jen selter is but I want a body like that. 
Anyway my main question is what do I do different to get a body like hers and around how long would it take me 
Appreciate it so much!!! THANKYOU

Comment: Just to add, a body like hers takes strict attention to diet, and a LOT more than "10 minutes of cardio and core and weights and work on my legs". Try hours on each, not 10 minutes for all.

Comment: one of many answers http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24012/1039